# Referenciar admin no Django

Tags: api, django, chave-estrangeira, django-rest-framework

Preciso que na tabela de informativos faça uma referencia para o administrador que a criou mas não sei o jeito correto de fazer isso, usei models.ForeignKey porem de onde deve importar a classe Admin? seria de django.contrib.admin?

```
class Informativo(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='informativos', blank=True, null=True )
    data_pub = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    state = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    admin_id = models.ForeignKey( ???, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Informativo: {self.titulo}>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu pensamento está correto.

De forma geral, as classes do Admin são voltadas para montar a interface gráfica do `django-admin`. (aquela tela onde existe uma implementação do CRUD de cada um dos models que compõe a sua aplicação, e que podemos acessar através da rota `/admin`.)

O correto seria utilizar o modelo [`User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/), que faz parte do módulo `django.contrib.auth.models`

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Informativo(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='informativos', blank=True, null=True )
    data_pub = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    state = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    admin_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Informativo: {self.titulo}>'
```

Você pode consultar a [`documentação`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/) sobre a personalização de modelos no Django.

Comment: obrigado, mas nessa caso um usuário comum também poderia criar um informativo ou não?

Comment: Sim, se quiser que apenas um django superuser possa fazer essas ações, consulte a documentação do User, vai encontrar os métodos `is_staff` e  `is_superuser`, poderia verificar esses atributos através de uma validação antes de salvar o `Informativo`.

Comment: Existe também o atributo `is_active`.

Comment: muito obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Informativo(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='informativos', blank=True, null=True )
    data_pub = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    state = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    admin_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Informativo: {self.titulo}>'
```

Para verificar e validar se é um administrador (super usuário) que está criando o Informativo, além de bloquear o acesso na View o recomendado é implementar o método save() no seu modelo para garantir a regra de negócio. O problema neste caso é que você precisa obter dados da sessão do usuário logado ao executar a ação. E o Django não tem recursos nativos para acessar a request dentro do model. Para solucionar isso recomendo usar o módulo https://pypi.org/project/django-crum/ que fornece um middleware para o request do usuário na sessão. Um exemplo de implementação:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

# módulo crum
from crum import get_current_user

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  user = get_current_user()
  if user.is_superuser is False:
     raise PermissionDenied('Ilegal request.')

  self.admin_id = user

  super(Informativo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Cara o correto seria utilizar um modelForm, ou implementar a lógica na view.py. O dev poderia fazer um filtro usando o User.objects.get(id=admin_id) e fazer essa lógica. Sair instalado lib sem necessidade não é solução. O cara nem pediu isso.

Comment: @Danizavtz eu concordo que não é uma boa prática instalar módulos sem necessidade. Mas minha sugestão foi baseada na filosofia de arquitetura do django. A pergunta pelo que entendi era como fazer este relacionamento para um papel específico, e como faz parte das regras de negócio eu recomendo também validar no modelo para manter o desacoplamento. [Design philosophies] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/misc/design-philosophies/)

Comment: Da maneira que sugeriu está completamente em desacordo com o que o django promete e o link que postou, desse modo está misturando lógica de negócio com camada de dados.

Comment: A arquitetura de camadas do django é um pouco diferente da convencionalmente conhecida e propagada. Sobre a questão em si, fato é que quando for necessário substituir a camada de apresentação  (View), na sua abordagem mais regras de negócio deverão ser obrigatoriamente reimplementadas gerando esforço adicional.

Comment: Mas você está colocando um acoplamento desnecessário na aplicação. Pois não sabe se será necessário substituir a camada de apresentação. O correto seria colocar essa lógica então no modelform. E não adicionar uma dependência. Além do mais a lib sugerida está em versão 0.7.9 e não colocou detalhadamente como configurar a lib para uso.